# Java cannot resolve org.apache.activemq.util

Tags: java, apache, gradle

Fairly new to Java and Gradle. My project cannot resolve 
import org.apache.activemq.util.RecoverableRandomAccessFile;

**Code snippet:**

```
package org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.util;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.activemq.util.RecoverableRandomAccessFile;
```

**build.gradle snippet:**

```
dependencies 

  compile project(':caffeine')

compile libraries.guava


  testCompile test_libraries.junit

  testCompile test_libraries.truth

  testCompile test_libraries.easymock

  testCompile test_libraries.guava_testlib

  compile group: 'org.apache.activemq', name: 'activemq-kahadb-store', version: '5.13.3'

  compile group: 'org.apache.activemq', name: 'activemq-all', version: '5.10.0'
```

why will this not resolve? I really would like to get this working. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a repositories section to your build.gradle file.

```
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}
```

Also, I assume that for simplicity sake you've omitted a lot of your build.gradle file (like the curly braces surrounding your dependencies).  If not, then there's a lot more work to do here.

Comment: Lanemax you are correct I left out brackets for simplicity I added you suggestion, ran ./gradlew clean build -x test --stacktrace, and relaunched Spring. No Dice, didn't work. However, when I right-clicked on the project, clicked Gradle (STS), Refresh ALL, it worked!

I am perplexed why the clean build did not get updated into the IDE, thoughts? What's the proper procedure for building?